# Laravel 5.4 - Reset Password change "email" column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm working with differing versions of Laravel and have built an addon that uses Laravel 5.4, Which unfortunatley is using a DB that references Laravel 3 **sic**

The "**users**" table has a column titled "**user_email**".

On the reset password, I want to change the DB Query to check against "user_email" not "email". As I currently get the error :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause'
```

SQL Query that it's trying to run is :

```
SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = user@user.co.uk limit 1
```

Is there any way of changing this to suit?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show your query?

Comment: Sure : SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = xyz@something.co.uk limit 1

Comment: I checked files in [`Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/). The `email` column is hardcoded.

Comment: Which method is it hardcoded in @OrkhanAlikhanov ?

Comment: If you're using the stand 5.4 User model and authentication, you should be able to add a function named "getEmailForPasswordReset()" in your user model.

Comment: @StuBlackett : did you solve this issue ?

Comment: Hi @user2486 - I didn't. In the end, I renamed all my columns and changed things around to suit the default db_table. Was shocked at how hard it was to do what I was asking

Answer (score 3):

For correctly custom the Column email you need do some change, first need override that method (getEmailForPasswordReset and routeNotificationFor) into model User:

```
public function getEmailForPasswordReset()
{
    return $this->email_user;
}

public function routeNotificationFor($driver)
{
    if (method_exists($this, $method = 'routeNotificationFor'.Str::studly($driver))) {
        return $this->{$method}();
    }

    switch ($driver) {
        case 'database':
            return $this->notifications();
        case 'mail':
            return $this->email_user;
        case 'nexmo':
            return $this->phone_number;
    }
}
```

and implement:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
```

into ForgotPasswordController need override the method called sendResetLinkEmail and validateEmail:

```
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateEmail($request);

    // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
    // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
    // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
    $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
        $request->only('email_user')
    );

    return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($response)
                : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
}

protected function validateEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['email_user' => 'required|email']);
}
```

Afther you need Override some method (validateNewPassword, validatePasswordWithDefaults, reset) from PasswordBroker, but we need.

1. Created a **CustomPasswordResetServiceProvider** inside App\Providers where I registered  a **CustomPasswordBrokerManager** instance.

   ```
   namespace App\Providers;
   use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
   use App\Services\CustomPasswordBrokerManager; 
   class CustomPasswordResetServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{
       protected $defer = true;

       public function register()
       {
           $this->registerPasswordBrokerManager();
       }

       protected function registerPasswordBrokerManager()
       {
           $this->app->singleton('auth.password', function ($app) {
               return new CustomPasswordBrokerManager($app);
           });
       }

       public function provides()
       {
           return ['auth.password'];
       }
   }
   ```
2. In **config/app.php** commented out line:
   `//Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,`
   and added:
   `App\Providers\CustomPasswordResetServiceProvider::class,`
3. Inside App\Services folder created a **CustomPasswordBrokerManager** and copied the context of the default **PasswordBrokerManager** located at:
   Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBrokerManager.php
   Then modified the function **resolve** to return an instance of my **CustomPasswordProvider** class.

   ```
   protected function resolve($name)
   {
       $config = $this->getConfig($name);
       if (is_null($config)) {
           throw new InvalidArgumentException("Password resetter [{$name}] is not defined.");
       }

       return new CustomPasswordBroker(
           $this->createTokenRepository($config),
           $this->app['auth']->createUserProvider($config['provider'])
   );
   }
   ```
4. Finally inside App\Services folder I created a **CustomPasswordBroker** class which extends default **PasswordBroker** located at:
   Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker and overridden the functions that I needed.

   ```
   use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker as BasePasswordBroker;    

   class CustomPasswordBroker extends BasePasswordBroker    
   {    
   // override the method validateNewPassword, validatePasswordWithDefaults and reset, you can take from Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker   

   }
   ```

Not sure if this is the best implementation.

Regards :)

Comment: Didn't work for me in Laravel 5.7 therefore -1 for that.

Comment: if you can see is just for Laravel 5.4 NOT FOR LARAVEL 5.7, first see all the post, then commit and rate the answer, thanks for nothing

Answer (score 0):

Add a class variable in `ResetPasswordController`

```
 protected $username = 'user_email';
```

Also add in `LoginController` for login purpose

Comment: Hi, This doesn't appear to work. Still asking for email in the SQL Error.

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to your `LoginController`

```
public function username()
{
    return 'user_email';
}
```